# How to use scanf function for an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I want to find the date,month and year through a given set of numbers using the array and pointers.I am writing the program to learn C.

Below is the output:

Enter the number : 22102013
Today is the day is 22,month is 10 and the year is 2013.

And i have wrote the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char date [11];

    char days []="DD";
    char month[]="MM";
    char year []="YYYY";

    printf("Enter the year that you want \n");
    scanf ("%d",&date[11]);


    char *my_pointer = date;
    days[0] = *(my_pointer);
    days[1] = *(my_pointer+1);


    month[0]=*(my_pointer+2);
    month[1]=*(my_pointer+3);

    year [0]=*(my_pointer+4);
    year [1]=*(my_pointer+5);
    year [2]=*(my_pointer+6);
    year [3]=*(my_pointer+7);

printf("Today the day is %s,the month is %s and the year is %s",days,month,year);
    return 0;
}
```

Also i had not initialized the array size but it kept raising error for declaration of the array.

Comment: `scanf ("%d",&date[11]);` -> `scanf ("%d", date);`

Comment: And instead of `days[0] = *(my_pointer)` etc. you can write simply `days[0] = date[0]` ; `days[1] = date[1]`, `days[2] = date[2]` etc.

Comment: I'm assuming you really want something like `scanf("%10s", date)`

Comment: _" but it kept raising error"_: who raises which error when you do what?

Comment: The compiler kept raising the error: array size missing in 'date'

Comment: Your array is 11 characters long, and the indexes run from 0 to 10.  date[11] is one character beyond the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your scanf should have been like this `scanf ("%s",date);`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char date [11];

    char days []="DD";
    char month[]="MM";
    char year []="YYYY";

    printf("Enter the year that you want \n");
    scanf ("%s",date);


    char *my_pointer = date;
    days[0] = *(my_pointer);
    days[1] = *(my_pointer+1);


    month[0]=*(my_pointer+2);
    month[1]=*(my_pointer+3);

    year [0]=*(my_pointer+4);
    year [1]=*(my_pointer+5);
    year [2]=*(my_pointer+6);
    year [3]=*(my_pointer+7);

printf("Today the day is %s,the month is %s and the year is %s",days,month,year);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char date[11];

  char days[] = "DD";
  char month[] = "MM";
  char year[] = "YYYY";

  printf("Enter the year that you want \n");
  scanf("%10s", date);  // limit input to 10 chars to prevent buffer overflow

  days[0] = date[0];
  days[1] = date[1];

  month[0] = date[2];
  month[1] = date[3];

  year[0] = date[4];
  year[1] = date[5];
  year[2] = date[6];
  year[3] = date[7];

  printf("Today the day is %s, the month is %s and the year is %s", days, month, year);
  return 0;
}
```

or even simpler:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char date[11];

  char days[] = "DD";
  char month[] = "MM";
  char year[] = "YYYY";

  printf("Enter the year that you want \n");
  scanf("%10s", date);

  memcpy(days,  date + 0, 2);
  memcpy(month, date + 2, 2);
  memcpy(year,  date + 4, 4);

  printf("Today the day is %s, the month is %s and the year is %s", days, month, year);
  return 0;
}
```

Example:

> Enter the year that you want
>   01022019
>   Today the day is 01, the month is 02 and the year is 2019

But be aware that this is very incovenient, because you don't check at all if the input is plausible, try to enter `abcdefg` instead of `01022019` and see what happens.